# How to vertical align text with center of image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

So I have an image "blah.jpg" and a name "Name" in HTML.

```
    <img src="blah.jpg"> Name
```

I want to make it so that the Name is center aligned with the center of the blah.jpg image instead of the text "Name" having a baseline at the bottom of the image.

What is the best way to accomplish this with no tables using CSS3 if possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I vertical center text next to an image in html/css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967022/how-do-i-vertical-center-text-next-to-an-image-in-html-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vertical-align: middle on your img element: http://jsfiddle.net/Z35pw/ .

Answer (score 3):

In the page:

```
<img src="blah.jpg" class="centered"> Name
```

In css file:

```
img.centered {vertical-align:middle;}
```

No need for display: inline-block (which is not supported in some old browsers)

Comment: Well, technically images are inline, not inline-block, but in this case, you're correct, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner, without defining extra objects or attributes, simply add `style="vertical-align:middle"` inside the `<img .../>` tag.