# How do I get words to the right of the picture?

Tags: html, image, words

I am brand new to html and I hit a wall trying to get words to the right of a picture and the picture be to the left.  I have searched this site and I found [How do I vertical center text next to an image in html/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967022/how-do-i-vertical-center-text-next-to-an-image-in-html-css) where the code works to an extent.  I have a paragraph that I type but half the paragraph goes under the picture plus the picture is in the center.

Please help.

Comment: post the HTML and CSS you've

Comment: `img { float: left; }`

Comment: have you done something?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5198514/1354251 The selected answer has two jsfiddle's that show exactly what you are describing and the code that makes it happen. It has a good explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, use

```
float: left;
```

Here's an example :

http://jsfiddle.net/6236Q/1/

If you want the text to go below the picture, remove the `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks, I am putting the float left next to the img.  I'll show you what I did.  <img { float: left; } src="link"> text.  That didn't work. I also went to that site and did the <p> and then my text just disappears and my pic is not to the left.

Comment: You're not declaring the CSS correctly, check this link for starters - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
</div>
```

margin-right is not necessary, but looks better.